# Error sending notification through firebase function flutter

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

- I am trying to send push notification to the user whenever the new event is added into the firestore of the firebase.
- Whenever I do so it returns me the error saying `Error sending notification`
- `node.js`

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().functions);

var newData;

exports.messageTrigger = functions.firestore.document('Messages/{messageId}').onCreate(async(snapshot, context)=> {
    if(snapshot.empty){
        console.log('No Devices');
        return;
    }
    var tokens = ['mobile-token'];

    newData = snapshot.data();

    var payload = {
        notification : {title: 'Push Title', body: 'Push body', sound: 'default'}, 
        data: {click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK', message: newData.message},
    };
    try{
        const response = await admin.messaging.sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        console.log('Notification sent successfully');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error sending notifications');
    }
});
```

- I am passing the mobile token in place of `mobile-token`

[image]

Comment: Try `console.log(err)`?

Comment: I have updated the question with the solution thanks a lot for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

- **SOLUTION**
- Changing `admin.messaging.sendToDevice()` to
  `const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload)`
- As `admin.messaging.sendToDevice()` is not a method